# JavaScript assignment explanation

Tags: javascript

I'm working off w3schools.com and I generally try to read through the code and make sense of what line of code does what, and I am a little confused on this code:

```
function myFunction() {
 var message, x;
 message = document.getElementById("message");
 message.innerHTML = "";
 x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
 try { 
    if(x == "") throw "empty";
    if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
    x = Number(x);
    if(x < 5) throw "too low";
    if(x > 10) throw "too high";
 }
 catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
 }
}
```

on the section:

```
var message, x;
message = document.getElementById("message");
message.innerHTML = "";
x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
```

Does the first line declare both variables message and x? The second line makes sense, but on the third line is it declaring undefined? And what exactly does the fourth line do?

Comment: @AndrewLi only it's not initializing `message` to an empty string. On the second line, an HTML element with the ID of "message" is being assigned to the `message` variable. On the 3rd line, *the HTML value* of the previously mentioned element is being set to an empty string.

Comment: _"Anyways, it still stands - `message` is reassigned to an empty string"_ - no, it's not. The `innerHTML` property of the HTML element that `message`references is set to the empty string, thereby clearing the element of all content.

Comment: @CBroe Ugh. I'm blind. Yes, `innerHTML` property is assigned to an empty string.

Comment: @AndrewLi, look at the code provided. `message` is an instance of a(n) [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) (so long as the element with the ID of "message" exists). On the 3rd line, the `innerHTML` property of the `message` variable is being set to an empty string, thus emptying the "html value" of the element on the page.

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld I know, just a simple misunderstanding. I missed the lines mentioned thus I didn't understand what you were saying.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you learn the developer tools that come with the browser (press F12 key). Each browser gives the sections different names but in Chrome look under to Source tab. Then learn how to set breakpoints and single step through your code. Seeing the code in action is better than trying to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. var message, x;
2. message = document.getElementById("message");
3. message.innerHTML = "";
4. x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
```

Line 1:  You can declare (and optionally assign values to) multiple variables, separated by commas, after a single var statement.

Line 3: is setting the 'property' innerHTML, on the object 'message', to the empty string.

Note : the object 'message', returned in line 2 would already have the property 'innerHTML'  of type string, (if the element with id="message" exists), because it is a particular type of object (an HTMLElement) but in general, you can assign any value to a previously undefined property on an object, and it will create that property. For example:

```
var obj = {}
alert (typeof obj.newproperty) // undefined
obj.newproperty = "hello"
alert (typeof obj.newproperty) // string
```

Line 4:

```
document.getElementById("demo")
```

is a reference to the element with id = "demo"

```
x = document.getElementById("demo").value
```

sets the variable, x, to the value of the property 'value' on that element (if it exists, or to undefined if it does not.)

Note : it no element with id="demo" exists then that line would throw an error trying to reference a property (value) on a null object.

Answer (score 0):

The first line declares both the message and the x variables. I don't know what you mean with declaring undefined, but the third line sets the content (inner HTML) of the message element to be an empty string. The last line sets to x the value attribute of the demo element. The value property contains the default value or the value a user types in a text field (or a value set by a script).

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunction() {
  var message, x; // declarations separated by a comma - end declarations with ;
  message = document.getElementById("message"); // assignment of an Element (which is an Object) to var message
  message.innerHTML = ""; // assignment to the Element's innerHTML property which writes inside the HTML Element itself - won't work on inputs (use .value)
  x = document.getElementById("demo").value; // assign the demo input value to var x
  try { // try things and send to catch if throw occurs
    if(x == "") throw "empty"; // == is a truthy test use === for more accuracy
    if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number"; // not numeric-ish - isNaN() works on strings too
    x = Number(x); // cast var x to a number - could also be done like x = +x;
    if(x < 5) throw "too low";
    if(x > 10) throw "too high";
  }
  catch(err) { // err argument receives throw if there is an error
    message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err; // assign
  }
}
```